# How to get single value from node taxonomy-type field

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy

I have this output:, and I want to get to "Center".

```
[field_affiliation] => Array(
   [und] => Array(
      [0] => Array(
         [tid] => 30
         [taxonomy_term] => stdClass Object(
            [tid] => 30
            [vid] => 2
            [name] => Center
```

Can I use this method?
`$affiliation=$node->field_affiliation['und']['0']['value']['taxonomy_term']['name'];`

or how can I use:
`drupal_array_get_nested_value();` - I cannot understand the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it will work 
as the name is under the object 'taxonomy_term'

`$affiliation=$node->field_affiliation['und']['0']['taxonomy_term']->name;`